# iOS Core Plot: backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: failed to map

Tags: ios, ipad, core-animation, core-plot

I have a problem with Core Plot on a iPad App that I've developed. My entire app uses ARC.

My app as 9 viewControllers, in each viewcontroller there is a Core Plot graph with 2 or 3 scatter plots.

After iterating those views for 8 or 9 times (back and forward) some graphs disappears and the error log of the iPad shows the following:

> ```
> Sep  7 18:12:24 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: failed to map 2263232 bytes (3)
> Sep  7 18:12:24 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: missing mask layer 0x0
> Sep  7 18:12:24 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: serialization error from context 1173490153
> Sep  7 18:12:24 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: failed to map 2263232 bytes (3)
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: missing mask layer 0x0
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: serialization error from context 1173490153
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> Sep  7 18:12:25 Mio-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
> ```

I'm not getting any memory warning (didReceiveMemoryWarning) before the graphs disappears.
I've used also the Allocation instrument but the trend doesn't grow up during the iterations.

The strange thing is also:
If I run the app in this way:
view1 --> view2 --> view3 --> view4 --> view5 --> view6 --> view7
the graphs doesn't disappear (after 200 iterations).

If I run the app in this way:
view1 --> view2 --> view3 --> view4 --> view5 --> view6 --> view7 --> view8
the graphs disappear after 49 iterations

If I run the app in this way:
view1 --> view2 --> view3 --> view4 --> view5 --> view6 --> view7 --> view8 --> last view
the graphs disappear after 7 iterations.

Is also interesting to know that:
view3 and view6, view4 and view7, view5 and view8 are specular (they are two classes presenting the same graphs with only different variables)

This is the way I've created the dealloc method (since I'm using ARC), are there any issues?

```
-(void)dealloc
{    
    touchPlotBall = nil; //(CPTScatterPlot)
    dataSourceLinePlot= nil; //(CPTScatterPlot)
    dataSourceSLinePlot = nil; //(CPTScatterPlot)

    [scatterPlotViewValue removeFromSuperview];  //(CPTGraphHostingView)
    scatterPlotViewValue=nil; //(CPTGraphHostingView)

    [scatterPlotViewBall removeFromSuperview]; //(CPTGraphHostingView)
    scatterPlotViewBall=nil; //(CPTGraphHostingView)

    self.delegate = nil; //(id<view7ControllerDelegate> delegate;)

}
```

Has anyone an answer or suggestion on this problem?

Thanks in advice

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using?

Comment: I'm using Core Plot 1.3 and I also tried to use the last pre-release version, without solving the issue.

Comment: is this solved ? I am using SwiftCharts but getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to follow my answer only if your job is not done by core plot.

In the past I  too was using core plot but it is bit complex process.

Its better to have an alternate solution.

Like you can use javascript,css,html and with such support you can load it as html string in webview easily with very less effort.

Have a look at this http://www.rgraph.net/ which I started using and it would be a boon for ios developer to have complex and variety of charts to use with less effort.

Comment: Actually Core Plot is working well and my project is already finished. I would prefer to fix the issue instead of redevelop the entire project.